# How does %JAVA_HOME% work in Windows PATH?

Tags: java, windows, path, environment-variables, puppet

I am using Puppet to automate the installation of java.  When doing this we first set the `JAVA_HOME environment` to whatever version of Java we are installing.  Then we have it prepend `%JAVA_HOME%` to Windows `PATH`.  That way if any other version of java is being used it will not use it and instead use whatever is in `JAVA_HOME`.  The issue I am running in to is when I run `dir %JAVA_HOME%` I get back

> "The system cannot find the path specified"

Yet when I `echo %JAVA_HOME%` it gives me the correct path to the JDK.

Should I expect `dir %JAVA_HOME%` to show me the directory contents? If not, why?  We have another program that works with the exact same Puppet method and when doing `dir M2_HOME` (maven) it will correctly print out the directory contents.

`Java -version` still works

Comment: you need to remove bin from java home and add %java_home%/bin

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove bin from java home and add %java_home%/bin

Answer (score -1):

Strange resolution.  The original way we were doing it does work.  However `JAVA_HOME` can not be `C:\Program Files\xxxxxxx`  it needs to be `C:\PROGRA~1\xxxxxx` for it to list directory contents.

Comment: No, it doesn't - you just need to put quote marks around it as per Elliott's comment.

Comment: I assure you, that did not work either.  It only works when using `PROGRA~1` not `Program Files`.  Windows can not handle the embedded space.

Comment: Of course Windows can handle the embedded space.  Since Windows paths often have embedded spaces someone would have noticed long before now if it didn't!  Just to be sure, though, I just tried `dir "%ProgramFiles%"` and it worked perfectly.  Whatever your problem is, that's not it.  Perhaps you had a stray space at the beginning or end of `%JAVA_HOME%` ?  Or you are running the `dir` command in an unusual context, e.g., via Puppet, or from a third-party shell?